# Limit My text to three lines with varied width

Tags: html, css

Is there a solution to fix content of my `p` to three lines.

```
<div><p>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</p></div>

div{
  height:300px;
  width:auto;
  font-size:40px;
}
```

The current text should occupy 3 lines and further if text changed, only the width should change and the content should be adjusted in 3 lines.

Thanks in advance.

P.S:

Please see the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/ME3Pd/)

Here the content settles in 3 lines, now if i add some content to the p tag, it would go to the fourth line, changing height and fixing the width... now i want exactly reverse of it.. wat ever i dow height should be fixed and width should vary.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for....

Comment: IMO, What you can do is limiting the height of the paragraph/division to 3 lines, but you won't have any control on the children and/or how they grow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><p>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</p></div>

<style>

div {
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

other  way   you can go

```
<div><p>Lorem ispum <br/> Lorem  ispum <br/> Lorem ispum <br/> </p></div>
```

and the third way is

```
<div><p>Lorem ispum Lorem ispum Lorem ispum</p></div>

<style>

div {
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 300px;
    display:table-caption
}
</style>
```

Comment: now if content added, width would be fixed and height changes.. i want the reverse of it.....

Comment: content not limited to three lines in the above fiddle that u have provided right!!

Comment: have you find this helpfull